# can't upload image with roxyfileman with php in iis8

Tags: php, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I used roxyfileman with tinymce4 in lot of project on wamp and server. but this time I want to run my php code on IIS8.5 , but when i want to upload image the roxyfileman can't do it for me and just give me a simple "error" message. I also can't rename a uploaded image too.any body have any idea about this? how can i resolve this problem?
i check IIS mime type and json mime type were added.

[image]

Comment: i change my destination folder permisision for iis user , and the problem sloved. and now I can upload iamges and rename them.

Comment: I think you should answer your own question. (And check its title - more useful with IIS8.5?)

Answer (score 0):

after on day struggling i change my destination folder permisision for iis user , and the problem sloved. and now I can upload iamges and rename them.